# Как сделать чтобы на каждом изображении при наведении курсора появлялся текст

Tags: html, css

```
<pre>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/style.css">
    <title>Home Work №5 Студенков Анатолій</title>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="background"></div>
    <center>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="destination">
                <h1>our destination</h1>
                <h3>choose your next destination</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Line_1">
            <div class="card_1"> 
                <img class="content_1"  src="./img/image 1 (7).png" alt="1">
                <img class="content_2"  src="./img/image 2.png" alt="2">
                <img class="content_3"  src="./img/image 3.png" alt="3">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="Line_2">
                <img class="content_4"  src="/img/image 4.png" alt="4">
                <img class="content_5"  src="./img/image 5.png" alt="5">
                <img class="content_6"  src="./img/image 6.png" alt="6">
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>

</body>

</html>
body{
    background-color: rgb(196, 191, 193);
}

.content{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.destimation{
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #020953;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

h1{
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
h3{
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 15px;
}
.line_1 .line_2{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.center{
    margin: auto;
}
.line_1, .line_2{
position:relative;   
width:300px;
height:400px;
}




</pre>
```

Comment: Во-первых, тег `<center>` уже давно не приветствуется - не нужно копипастить всё подряд. Во-вторых, пробелы в путях к файлам - плохая практика. В-третьих, где и какой текст должен появляться?

Comment: Вечер добрый, спасибо за рекомендации, я только учусь. Есть задача, 6 картинок в два ряда, при наведении на картинку курсора должен появляться текст 100$, Я просто не могу понять как сделать так чтобы применить сразу к 2м блокам, а не к каждому изображению отдельно.

Comment: На счет <center>, не копипаст, а просмотр ресурсов. Буду благодарен если подскажите как заменить <center>

Comment: Текст который отображается при наведении на картинку указывается в атрибут "alt" тега img. Там где у Вас 1,2,3,4,5..

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если уж совсем извращаться, так можно сделать примерно так (я не вычищал уже нюансы, сама идея - попробуйте увести курсор с первой картинки на вторую и обратно)

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Work №5 Студенков Анатолій</title>
    <style>
body{
    background-color: rgb(196, 191, 193);
}

.content{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.destimation{
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #020953;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

h1{
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
h3{
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 15px;
}
.line_1 .line_2{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.center{
    margin: auto;
}
.line_1, .line_2{
position:relative;   
width:300px;
height:400px;
}

#card_1_1 {
    --text-visible: hidden;
}
#card_1_1:hover {
    --text-visible: visible;
}
#card_1_1 #textimg_1 {
   visibility: var(--text-visible);
}
    </style>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="background"></div>
    <center>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="destination">
                <h1>our destination</h1>
                <h3>choose your next destination</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Line_1">
            <div class="card_1"> 
                <div id="card_1_1" style="position: relative">
                    <img id="img_1" class="content_1"  src="https://avatarko.ru/img/kartinka/33/multfilm_lyagushka_32117.jpg" alt="1">
                    <div id="textimg_1" style="position:absolute; bottom: 50%; left: 50%; z-index: 100;"><h1>100$</h1></div>
                </div>
                <div  id="card_1_2" style="position: relative">
                    <img class="content_2"  src="https://kartinkin.net/uploads/posts/2022-03/thumbs/1648037518_37-kartinkin-net-p-krasivie-kartinki-na-vaiber-49.jpg" alt="2">
                </div>
                <img id="card_1_3" class="content_3"  src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS28FZFtMvSKapZFq-7hKfiQ7IIa_Z67XJv1zUS6caRFjMbhe8S_F24xEZP6PWwx0PRMC4&usqp=CAU" alt="3">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="Line_2">
                <img class="content_4"  src="https://www.ixbt.com/img/r30/00/02/16/70/IMG3249.jpg" alt="4">
                <img class="content_5"  src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/krisdog/krisdog2005/krisdog200500053/146854659-cell-mobile-phone-mascot-cartoon-character.jpg?ver=6" alt="5">
                <img class="content_6"  src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/krisdog/krisdog1812/krisdog181200047/121753327-a-cell-or-mobile-phone-christmas-mascot-cartoon-character-with-a-santa-claus-hat-on-giving-a-double-.jpg?ver=6" alt="6">
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>

</body>
```